# Eclipse unhundled event loop exception, after using "Configure Eclipse for ..." button

Tags: eclipse, exception

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjSyG.png)

there is a exception stack trace if that can be help you

```
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:65)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:305)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:239)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:494)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:487)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:431)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(AbstractContributionItem.java:446)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem.lambda$2(AbstractContributionItem.java:472)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4428)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4238)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3817)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
36 more
```

Comment: It is the "Caused by" part of the stack trace that is more important -  that points to some non-Eclipse plug-in causing the problem.

Comment: Your Eclipse is more than 5 years and 19 releases behind. Please upgrade to the current version (2022-12). Please make sure the used software is up to date when asking a question. In the _Error Log_ view, you can select the error, hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_ (instead of double-clicking and copying only parts from details dialog). According to the stack trace from the screenshot, the issue seems to be caused by `wlpfo.dev.envsetup.git.GitSetupUtils` which is from a plugin you have installed and that I don't know.

Comment: @howlger thanks for answer, but I can't update the Eclipse.
Yeah this is my first question and I can make some inaccuracies.
We all using the same version of Eclipse and same plugins, but only in my notebook I have problems like this, that's the problem.

Comment: Well as we already said the problem appears to be in this `wlpfo.dev.envsetup.git.GitSetupUtils` class. That is not part of standard Eclipse and doing a quick search I can find no information about it, so it is very hard for us to help.